# save array in state, and edit later

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I save the state for my array, my suggestion was something like `this.setstate=({maze: "hello"})`. I think its something with `.bind` but I'm a totally beginner.
i want to render x x y buttons and, save x x y times "hello" in my state .

My second question: Is there later a way to edit my maze state, I thought about the id, i set in my code too. I want that my state looks later, for example like this : maze: "hello", "hello", "bye, "hello".

`{Array(this.state.x*this.state.y).fill(0).map((b,i)=>(<button  id={i}  />  ))}`

my state:

```
state={
   x:'',
   y:'',
   maze:[],
}
```

Comment: If you may split your questions into separate posts and supply both with corresponding code samples that reproduce your problem, as well as provide expected result that would've raise your chances to get relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but this is something I got:

```
  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        maze: []
    }

   this.hello = this.hello.bind(this);
   this.bye = this.bye.bind(this);
  }

  hello() {
    this.setState({...this.state.maze.push("hello")});
  }

   bye() {
    this.setState({...this.state.maze.push("bye")});
  }

  render() {
  console.log(this.state.maze)

    return (
        <div>
        <div>
          {this.state.maze}
        </div>
          <button id="hello" onClick={() => this.hello()}>Hello!</button>
        <button id="bye" onClick={() => this.bye()}>Bye!</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

You can see how it works with this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha2xw9gq/4/)